# SheetJS not exporting complete decimal values

Tags: xlsx, js-xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to export json data to csv file using SheetJS.  The json is like this:

```
[
    {col1: item1, col2: 1462.47907042},
    {col1: item2, col2: 3327.28233473}
]
```

And the function to export is the following:

```
public exportToCSV(json: any[], fileName: string): void {
  const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, fileName);
  XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${fileName}.csv`);
}
```

But when it's export to csv file, the decimal points are incomplete.  The csv file shows

```
col1,col2
item1,1462.47907
item2,3327.282335
```

Why is SheetJS truncating the decimal points?  How to export the complete decimal values?

*** UPDATE ***
Looks like, if I export the data as .xlsx, I get all the decimal values.  But if i export as .csv, I get incomplete decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

To export json as csv better to use "papaparse" (`npm install papaparse`) 
Then you can save it by using "fs". Follow the way code below.

```
const papa = require('papaparse');
const fs = require('fs');

const rJson = [
    { col1: 'item1', col2: 1462.47907042 },
    { col1: 'item2', col2: 3327.28233473 }
  ];

const yourPath = `D:\\testjs\\stackoverflow.csv`;
const csv = papa.unparse(rJson);
fs.writeFileSync(yourPath, csv, 'utf8');
```

Here is your csv output.

```
col1,col2
item1,1462.47907042
item2,3327.28233473
```